# Drawing perturbations from a fat-tailed distribution

Tags: distributions, python, t-distribution

I am wanting to apply random perturbations to a dynamical system. I woul dlike these perturbations to come from a fait tailed distrubtuion. I thought of using a t-distribution with a low dof number (1?). I would like the values to values to fall between different values: for instance, can I have them fall mainly (95%) between -0.1 to 0.1. How would i generalize this to any value, say from -A to A, where A could be 0.001 to 0.2. I would like to draw 1000 samples.

Answer (score 1):

The Cauchy distribution in `R` (`rcauchy`, `pcauchy`, etc) gives you the ability to change the scale (something like variance) while maintaining the super-fat tails of the $t_1$ distribution. You can play with the scale parameter to find what value gives you the $0.025$ quantile at $-0.1$ like you want.

The theory behind this is that you’re stretching or compressing $t_1$ but not really changing the shape. Think about a normal distribution with different variance parameters. Sure, the curve is different, but the spirit is the same: a mound shape.

Be warned that the tails of a Cauchy distribution are *really* heavy, so heavy that Cauchy doesn’t even have an expected value!

Answer (score -1):

A fat-tailed distribution with well-defined moments, amiable to statistical testing is the log-normal distribution. To quote [from Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Log-normal_distribution):

> Thus, if the random variable X is log-normally distributed, then Y = ln(X) has a normal distribution. Equivalently, if Y has a normal distribution, then the exponential function of Y, X = exp(Y), has a log-normal distribution. A random variable which is log-normally distributed takes only positive real values. It is a convenient and useful model for measurements in exact and engineering sciences as well as medicine, economics and other fields, e.g. for energies, concentrations, lengths, financial returns and other amounts.

Comment: Lognormal distributions cannot produce any negative values, so how do you propose applying them to this question??